# How to setup database view fixture?

Tags: php, cakephp

Is it possible to setup a fixture that would create a database view instead of database table in CakePHP? It seems to be inefficient to have the same data in a fixture that creates a table and in another fixture that is supposed to be a database view.

Comment: Did you ever solve this?

Comment: Yes, I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it this way where view_my_model.sql contains SQL that generates the database view:

```
class ViewMyModelFixture extends AppFixture {

    public function create($DboSource) {
        $path = APP . 'Config' . DS . 'sql' . DS . 'view_my_model.sql';
        $File = new File($path);
        if (!$File->exists()) {
            throw new CakeException($path . ' does not exist');
        }
        if (!$File->readable()) {
            throw new CakeException($path . ' is not readable');
        }
        $sql = $File->read();
        if (empty($sql)) {
            throw new CakeException($path . ' has no SQL');
        }
        try {
            $DboSource->execute($sql);
            $this->created[] = $DboSource->configKeyName;
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            $msg = __d('cake_dev', 'Fixture creation for "%s" failed "%s"', $this->table, $exception->getMessage());
            CakeLog::error($msg);
            trigger_error($msg, E_USER_WARNING);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function drop($DboSource) {
        try {
            $sql = 'DROP VIEW ' . $DboSource->fullTableName($this->table) . ";";
            $DboSource->execute($sql);
            $this->created = array_diff($this->created, array($DboSource->configKeyName));
        } catch (Exception $exception) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public function truncate($DboSource) {
        return;
    }
}
```